# How is the satisfaction predicate usually defined?

Tags: logic

I came across two axioms involving the satisfaction predicate (in sequent calculus),

(SatI):
$$
P(z_1, z_2, ..., z_n) \vdash Sat^n(z_1, z_2, ..., z_n, \ulcorner P(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)\urcorner )
$$
(SatE):
$$
Sat^n(z_1, z_2, ..., z_n, ⌜P(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)⌝ \vdash P(z_1, z_2, ..., z_n)
$$

Where $P$ is an n-ary predicate, $Sat^n$ is an (n+1)-ary Satisfaction predicate, and the quote ⌜⌝ is some formula naming device (i.e. Godel code).

I'm wondering if the following modified version, which is less restrictive, is problematic:

(SatI'):
$$
\Phi[z_1/x_1][z_2/x_2]...[z_n/x_n] \vdash Sat^n(z_1, z_2, ..., z_n, \ulcorner\Phi\urcorner)
$$
(SatE'):
$$
Sat^n(z_1, z_2, ..., z_n, \ulcorner\Phi\urcorner) \vdash \Phi[z_1/x_1][z_2/x_2]...[z_n/x_n]
$$

Here, $\Phi[z_1/x_1][z_2/x_2]...[z_n/x_n]$ is $\Phi$ with each occurence of $x_1$ replaced by $z_1$, $x_2$ replaced by $z_2$, etc.
Defining the Satisfaction predicate this way allows me to treat formulas with free variables as "predicates," instead of restricting formulas the $Sat^n$ can take to be some predicate P. For example, I can define the Heterological predicate as:
$$
H(z) \equiv \lnot Sat^1(z, \ulcorner x_1(x_1)\urcorner)
$$

My primary concern is if the modified versions allow inferences that would be invalid. I don't think it does, so long as we restrict $\Phi$ such that it has no free variables after substitution, but I'm not sure. Also, the satisfaction predicate should be taken as primitive, and we can ignore its consistency (it's probably not consistent as is, just like adding intro and elim rules for the truth predicate).

Comment: The Sat relation is defined inductively starting from the atomic formula case and then extended to connectives and quantifiers. How does your purported "general" case for the $(\text {Sat} \text {I})$ rule apply to e.g. the existential quantifier that is something like: 
$∃y \varphi (z_1, z_2, ..., z_n) \vdash \text {Sat}^{(n+1)}(z_1, z_2, ..., z_n, a, ⌜\varphi (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n, a)⌝) \text { for some } a$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Found an example where the satisfaction is defined via substitution into the formula, so I think my modified version is ok.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).